# GCM IntentService

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

i used this code for GCM , but when i got pushnotification , i got error like this :

```
> 08-24 09:28:31.670   25605-5683/icon.apkt E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
> EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-43597399078-11]
>     android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5503)
>             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1099)
>             at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChildFast(ViewGroup.java:4417)
>             at android.view.View.invalidateViewProperty(View.java:11201)
>             at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationUpdate(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:1047)
>             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateValue(ValueAnimator.java:1166)
>             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1102)
>             at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1131)
>             at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:616)
>             at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:639)
>             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
>             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
>             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Here is my code :

```
/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Device unregistered");
    generateNotification(context, "Device Unregistered", new Intent());
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 */
@Override
protected void onMessage(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Received message");
    if (intent == null) {

    } else {
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    String namaPelanggan = "", alamat = "", telepon = "", noGangguan = "";
    // {
    // "reportNumber" : "G5313111100001"
    // "status" : "Dalam Perjalanan",
    // "poskoId" : "538711",
    // "poskoName" : "POSKO DEPOK KOTA",
    // "reguId" : "6683",
    // "reguName" : "rdpk55",
    // "idPel" : "525060659230",
    // "namaPelanggan" : "SUPRIYADI" ,
    // "createBy" : "11387",
    // "createName" : "POSKODEPOK",
    // "namaPelapor" : ""SAMINAH,
    // "alamat" : "KP PANCORAN MAS",
    // "telepon" : "021234234",
    // "hp" : "081234234234",
    // "longitude" : "0",
    // "latitude" : "0"
    // }

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
            namaPelanggan = json.getString("namaPelanggan");
            alamat = json.getString("alamat");
            telepon = json.getString("telepon");
            noGangguan = json.getString("reportNumber");

            String total = "Gangguan baru diterima, NoGangguan = " + noGangguan
                    + " Pelapor = " + namaPelanggan + ", Lokasi = " + alamat
                    + ", Telepon = " + telepon;

            // final String nogang = noGangguan;
            try {
   //             GenericMethods.ShowToast(context, total);
                User user = new User();
                if (user.fromLocal(context)) {
                    GenericMethods.getGangguanOnline(context, user,
                            new onFinish() {
                                @Override
                                public void complete() {
                                    // DO NOTHING
                                    // Intent intent = null;
                                    //
                                    // Gangguan tugas = GenericMethods
                                    // .getGangguan(nogang);
                                    //
                                    // if (tugas == null) {
                                    // Log.i("RETURN", "NULL");
                                    // return;
                                    // }
                                    //
                                    // Log.i("SELECT", tugas.LASTSTATUS);
                                    // if (tugas.LASTSTATUS
                                    // .equalsIgnoreCase(WSDLConfig.status.status0))
                                    // {
                                    // intent = new Intent(context,
                                    // BerangkatActivity.class);
                                    // Log.d("GCM Open", tugas.LASTSTATUS);
                                    // } else if (tugas.LASTSTATUS
                                    // .equalsIgnoreCase(WSDLConfig.status.status1))
                                    // {
                                    // intent = new Intent(context,
                                    // SebelumActivity.class);
                                    // Log.d("GCM Open", tugas.LASTSTATUS);
                                    // } else if (tugas.LASTSTATUS
                                    // .equalsIgnoreCase(WSDLConfig.status.status2))
                                    // {
                                    // intent = new Intent(context,
                                    // SesudahActivity.class);
                                    // Log.d("GCM Open", tugas.LASTSTATUS);
                                    // } else if (tugas.LASTSTATUS
                                    // .equalsIgnoreCase(WSDLConfig.status.status3))
                                    // {
                                    // intent = new Intent(context,
                                    // SesudahActivity.class);
                                    // Log.d("GCM Open", tugas.LASTSTATUS);
                                    // } else if (tugas.LASTSTATUS
                                    // .equalsIgnoreCase(WSDLConfig.status.status4))
                                    // {
                                    // intent = new Intent(context,
                                    // SelesaiActivity.class);
                                    // Log.d("GCM Open", tugas.LASTSTATUS);
                                    // }
                                    //
                                    // if (intent != null) {
                                    // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    // intent.putExtra(
                                    // Configuration.put_runworkflowID,
                                    // tugas.REPORTNUMBER);
                                    // startActivity(intent);
                                    // }
                                    //    if (GenericMethods.activeActivity != null)
                                    //      ((MainActivity) GenericMethods.activeActivity)
                                    //            .getDaftarGangguanOffline();
                                }
                            });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper(context);
            db.insertGCMList(noGangguan, total);
            db.close();
            Log.i("GCM","GCM Notif");
            generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), total, new Intent(
                    getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are trying to show datas on UI using Background thread..So that you got this Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views exception.

Comment: Use handlers to interact with UI elements from GCMIntentService since it is a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is not about GCM, it is because you try to update your UI in intent service, intent service actually run in a separate thread. Android does not allow update UI in non-main thread.

Try to move your update UI code into main thread, here just an example:

```
    new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // put your update UI code here.
        }
    });
```